# Problem starting nodemon in Docker on Mac M1

Tags: docker, macos, yarnpkg, package.json, nodemon

I'm attempting to get a barebones node/express app running inside docker on a Mac M1, but I'm getting the following error when I try to spin up the Docker container:

```bash
> docker run -p 3000:8080 --name my-container --volume ${PWD}:/usr/src/app my-app

yarn run v1.22.19
$ nodemon server.js
/bin/sh: nodemon: Device timeout
error Command failed with exit code 127.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

If I run the 'start' command locally, I get no issue:

```bash
> yarn start
yarn run v1.22.18
$ nodemon server.js
[nodemon] 2.0.16
[nodemon] reading config ./package.json
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] or send SIGHUP to 6511 to restart
[nodemon] ignoring: node_modules/**/* docs/**/*
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
[nodemon] forking
[nodemon] child pid: 6513
[nodemon] watching 6 files
Example app listening at http://localhost:8080
```

My `package.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "name": "docker-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "pg": "^8.7.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": [
      "node_modules/*",
      "docs/*"
    ],
    "verbose": true,
    "delay": 2500
  }
}
```

... and my Dockerfile looks like this:

```
# select the base image
FROM node:14-alpine3.15

# Adding build tools to make yarn install work on Apple silicon / arm64 machines
RUN apk add --no-cache python2 g++ make

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies

COPY package.json ./
COPY yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

CMD [ "yarn", "start"]
```

As you can see I've tried adding a watch delay and explicitly excluding `node_modules`. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: Why would you run nodemon in the container? Is this supposed to be a dev or prod image?

Comment: Because I'm developing an app locally, that's going to be using Postgres in another container and a 3rd party app in another.

Comment: But _inside the container_ what changes need to be watched for?

Comment: ? Changes to the local folder - hence the --volume ${PWD}:/usr/src/app

Comment: OK, so: dev image.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, turns out it was down to an aliasing issue, in that the machine I'd been given to work on had podman aliased to docker. So the issue was down to podman. With podman removed and replaced by docker the Dockerfile ran perfectly!